# How to set the 'selected' Tab of the TabStrip to the first tab in Form `onSubmit`

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

How can I set the 'selected' Tab of the TabStrip to the first tab in Form `onSubmit`?

i.e. I need to call `tabStrip.setSelected(0)`, but in React methodology I'm not sure how to get a reference to the tabStrip?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Field, Form, FormElement } from '@progress/kendo-react-form';
import { Button } from '@progress/kendo-react-buttons';

import {
  TabStrip,
  TabStripSelectEventArguments,
  TabStripTab,
} from '@progress/kendo-react-layout';

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<number>(2);

  const handleSelect = (e: TabStripSelectEventArguments) => {
    setSelected(e.selected);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (dataItem) => {
    alert("Submit OK");
  };

return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      render={(formRenderProps) => (
        <div>
          <TabStrip selected={selected} onSelect={handleSelect}>
            <TabStripTab title="Tab 1 Title">
              <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
            </TabStripTab>
            <TabStripTab title="Tab 2 Title">
              <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
            </TabStripTab>
            <TabStripTab title="Tab 3 Title">
              <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
            </TabStripTab>
          </TabStrip>

          <span style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Button type={'submit'} icon="save" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Save
            </Button>
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
    ></Form>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mamtrq-6oshyg?file=app%2Fmain.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form` component from [`@progress/kendo-react-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-react-form) ([seen here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/form/))is handling the form submission in a particular way, and directly calling the `submit` method on the form element is not triggering the `onSubmit` prop.

If the underlying goal is to set the selected tab to the first one on form submission, we can achieve the desired behavior without the need to interact with the `TabStrip` component directly. We can control the selected tab by managing the state of the `selected` variable.

If a direct reference to the `TabStrip` is required for other purposes, you would typically use the `useRef` hook and the `ref` attribute. However, this is generally not needed when you can control the component through props and state, as we can do here.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<number>(2);

    const handleSelect = (e: TabStripSelectEventArguments) => {
        setSelected(e.selected);
        console.log("handleSelect called", e.selected);
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setSelected(0); // Set the selected tab to the first one
        console.log("handleSubmit called");
        alert("Submit OK");
    };

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        console.log("handleButtonClick called");
        handleSubmit(); // Call handleSubmit directly
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <TabStrip selected={selected} onSelect={handleSelect}>
                <TabStripTab title="Tab 1 Title">
                    <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
                </TabStripTab>
                <TabStripTab title="Tab 2 Title">
                    <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
                </TabStripTab>
                <TabStripTab title="Tab 3 Title">
                    <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
                </TabStripTab>
            </TabStrip>
            <span style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                <Button type={'button'} icon="save" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                    Save
                </Button>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = document.querySelector('my-app');
if (root) {
  createRoot(root).render(<App />);
}
```

We are directly calling the `handleSubmit` function from the `handleButtonClick` function, bypassing the form submission process. That approach make sures that the selected tab is set to the first one when the "Save" button is clicked.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mamtrq-hrtjuu?file=app%2Fmain.tsx).

---

If you want a fully native [`@progress/kendo-react-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-react-form)  option:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<number>(2);

  const handleSelect = (e: TabStripSelectEventArguments) => {
    setSelected(e.selected);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    setSelected(0); // Set the selected tab to the first one
    alert("Submit OK");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> {/* Handle form submission with native form */}
      <TabStrip selected={selected} onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <TabStripTab title="Tab 1 Title">
          <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
        </TabStripTab>
        <TabStripTab title="Tab 2 Title">
          <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
        </TabStripTab>
        <TabStripTab title="Tab 3 Title">
          <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
        </TabStripTab>
      </TabStrip>
      <div className="k-form-buttons">
        <button type={"submit"} className="k-button k-primary">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const root = document.querySelector('my-app');
if (root) {
  createRoot(root).render(<App />);
}
```

[stackblitz demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mamtrq-srmssy?file=app%2Fmain.tsx).